# Only return a value of a name, no duplicated name (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to redo everything with better examples.

This query was the first, and it shows everybody:

```
SELECT t2.name as name, t1.key as keyy, t1.value as valuee 
FROM player_storage t1 INNER JOIN players t2 on t2.id = t1.player_id 
WHERE t1.value > 0 AND t1.key IN (99781,99780,99777) 
ORDER BY keyy+0 DESC, valuee+0 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Real output:

| name | level | keyy | valuee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 558 | 99781 | 1 |
| BBBBB | 559 | 99780 | 1 |
| AAAAA | 558 | 99777 | 490 |
| BBBBB | 559 | 99777 | 470 |
| CCCCC | 361 | 99777 | 456 |

The thing wrong is that I don't want to see 99777 of the names who have 99781 or 99780, if they have one of the first, I just want to see that one, not their 99777.

@Craig helped me to get to this:

```
SELECT t2.name as name, t2.level as level, t1.key as keyy, t1.value as valuee
FROM player_storage t1 INNER JOIN players t2 on t2.id = t1.player_id
WHERE t1.value > 0 AND 

( 
    t1.key IN (99781, 99780) 
    OR 
    ( 
        t1.key IN (99777) 
        AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( 
            SELECT 1 FROM player_storage tx 
            WHERE tx.player_id = t1.player_id 
            AND tx.key > t1.key 
        )
    ) 
) 

ORDER BY keyy+0 DESC, valuee+0 DESC LIMIT 5
```

And I think it's what I need, but this is somehow skipping some results, see output:

| name | level | keyy | valuee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 558 | 99781 | 1 |
| BBBBB | 559 | 99780 | 1 |
| EEEEEE | 87 | 99777 | 189 |
| DDDDDD | 21 | 99777 | 145 |
| ZZZZZZ | 570 | 99777 | 2 |

This is hiding A and B results from 99777 as I wanted, but it should show C result as third, since on last output (from query above) he was the third with most 97777.

I think this query above is achieving my result, but somehow it's with this problem.

edit.
player_storage structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUcY4.png

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot follow your description of your data! Can you pls provide sample data, expected output, and actual output in **tabular format**?

Comment: I've tried to add tables with results, but on preview edit tables are fine, when i place the edit, it breaks, some help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.name as name, t2.level as level, t1.key as keyy, t1.value as valuee 
FROM player_storage t1 INNER JOIN players t2 on t2.id = t1.player_id 
WHERE t1.value > 0 
AND
(
    t1.key = 99781
    OR
    (
        t1.key IN (99780, 99777)
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM player_storage tx
            WHERE tx.player_id = t1.player_id
            AND tx.key > t1.key
        )
    )
)
ORDER BY keyy+0 DESC, valuee+0 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Edited to this:

`SELECT t2.name as name, t2.level as level, t1.key as keyy, t1.value as valuee 
FROM player_storage t1 INNER JOIN players t2 on t2.id = t1.player_id 
WHERE t1.value > 0 
AND
(
 t1.key IN (99781, 99780)
    OR
    (
        t1.key IN (99777)
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM player_storage tx
            WHERE tx.player_id = t1.player_id
            AND tx.key > t1.key
        )
    )
)
ORDER BY keyy+0 DESC, valuee+0 DESC LIMIT 5`

Exactly what I wanted, thank you so much.

Comment: I see - so if a player has both 99781 AND 99780 keys, you want both of those to display?  If that's the case, then your edit make sense

Comment: I tought that it worked as I wanted. But it's showing only 1 user with key 99777 and not returning all the 5 I ask on the end. I'll try to be more clear, but commenting is a bit hard. Only max 1 user will have the 99781 key, then there are max 2 with 99780 key, then I want to show who have most 99777 value until limit 5 total (on the 3 keys).

Comment: could you help whenever possible? sorry for tagging.

Comment: Hi @YuriAniceto - sorry, I've been unavailable for a few days.  To be honest, you should have enough guidance in those queries to be able to implement what you need.  You'll just need different combinations of the t1.key IN (...something) and the NOT EXISTS clause.  Have you had further attempts at a query to achieve the results you're after?  You could update your question with your progress so far

Comment: remade everything on the question, hope it helps.

Comment: @YuriAniceto, if I mock up your dataset on my MySQL server and then run the second query (in your question), I get the results that you are expecting - so, off the top of my head, I'm unsure why you are not.  Can you advise what the actual data-types are in your table structures?  Also, what are the primary keys on each table, and what existing indexes are there?  I'm thinking that potentially the data-type of the "value" column may be the cause of confusion

Comment: added picture with the table structure, the values come from a system, so I don't know if I can change some of that stuff. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm.... because the "key" and "value" columns are varchar/text, then your mathematical calculations, and inferred ordering, may not necessarily be working exactly as you expect.  Assuming that these columns really do only hold numeric values, then you could amend your query so that each reference to "key" or "value" is wrapped in a CAST() - eg. CAST(t1.key AS UNSIGNED) - including in the ORDER BY clause.  See if that makes a difference